# Spring EhCache configuration - Cannot find class [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean]

Tags: spring-mvc, caching, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

I need help with ehCache configuration. 
These what i did :

**ehcache.xml**  inside my src/main/resources folder

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect"
dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<cache name="allNodesCache"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
    eternal="false"
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
    transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

**ehCache configuration inside my applicationContext-web.xml**

```
<!--  ehCache configuration -->
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
<!-- EhCache library setup -->
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="ehcache.xml"/>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<!--  ehCache -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
       <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**My repository class:**

```
@Repository
```

public interface NodeRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
@Cacheable(value = "allNodesCache", key = "#node")
@Query("select new com.datum.fnd.domain.Node(c.idNode, c.name, c.address, c.description, c.point) from Node c")
```

**I got message like this :**
   Cannot find class [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'ehcache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean

Comment: Please add the different versions of the libraries used.

Comment: I have solved my problem with moving my ehcache.xml to the webapp folder

Answer (score 4):

Add the spring context support dependency to your classpath:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support